# Best way to merge and store multiple csv file using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, performance, csv

I'm working with a company that every day gives me a `CSV` file with about 25.000 rows.
The difference between `CSV` of one day and that of the day before is that in the newest one, some rows (many less than the total) are deleted and others are added. So the two files has about 24900 rows in common.

I have to store all the rows in the time.. so every day I have to update my table in DB with the current CSV.

I think about:

```
<?php
   $fh = fopen($actual_csv, 'r');
   $contents = fread($fh, filesize($actual_csv));
   fclose($fh);
   $fileLines = explode("\n", $contents);
   for ($i = 1; $i < count($fileLines) - 1; $i++) {
    $fieldList = explode(';', $fileLines[$i]);
        //$fieldList[0] is my unique id
        if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_where_i_store_all WHERE id='$fieldList[0]'"))<=0){
           mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_where_i_store_all (column names..) VALUES ('$fieldList[0],........')"); // there are many column so i don't write it..
        }
   }
?>
```

I think this is not very powerful and fast. is there any better way? thanks!!!

Comment: It seems more efficient to work on the diff of two `CSV` files, if the earlier one is available. Did you think in these lines already?

Comment: so u are talking about to store all in another csv file?

Comment: Yeah, in case you have the yesterday's file, you can use a CSV diff library to get the diff of today's file against the yesterday's one. The result would be those removed and those added, since yesterday. You can take appropriate action on these two sets. Hope this is clear.

Comment: i like ur proposal.. but where can i find csv diff php library? :) i google it but i find only code...

Comment: If you can use Perl module, then there would be some CPAN module.

Comment: if(! mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM table_where_i_store_all WHERE id='$fieldList[0]' LIMIT 1"))
    {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALTER TABLE table_where_i_store_all ADD UNIQUE( id );

```
$fileLines = explode("\n", $contents);
$linemax = count( $fileLines )-1;

if( $linemax < 1 ) // empty file?
  return;

$SQL = "INSERT IGNORE INTO table_where_i_store_all (column_names) VALUES ";

for ($i = 1; $i < $linemax; $i++) {
   $fieldList = explode(';', $fileLines[$i]);
   //$fieldList[0] is my unique id

   $SQL .= "('$fieldList[0],........'),";        
}
$SQL = substr( $SQL, 0, strlen($SQL)-1);  // remove extra comma from end
$res = mysql_query($SQL);
```

Answer (score 3):

create unique index on the `id` fields (maybe you've done in already) and use `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: It works like this: Try to insert; if it fails, just skip. This is the reason you need an unique index or another constrain that will fail if you try to add the same row.